# Typing Immutable.js Map in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, immutable.js

I'm a newbie in Typescript and  i'm trying to strongly type an Immutable Map (immutable.js library).

```
type AllowedValue =
    string |
    number |
    boolean |
    AllowedMap |
    AllowedList |
    TypedMap<any> |
    undefined;

interface AllowedList extends List<AllowedValue> {}

interface AllowedMap extends Map<string, AllowedValue> {}

export type MapTypeAllowedData<DataType> = {
    [K in keyof DataType]: AllowedValue;

};

export interface TypedMap<DataType extends MapTypeAllowedData<DataType>> extends Map<string, AllowedValue> {
    toJS(): DataType;
    get<K extends keyof DataType>(key: K, notSetValue?: DataType[K]): DataType[K];
    set<K extends keyof DataType>(key: K, value: DataType[K]): this;

}

const createTypedMap = <DataType extends MapTypeAllowedData<DataType>>(data: DataType): TypedMap<DataType> => Map(data) as any;
```

and I have this error.

```
Interface 'TypedMap<DataType>' incorrectly extends interface 'Map<string, AllowedValue>'.
  Types of property 'set' are incompatible.
    Type '<K extends keyof DataType>(key: K, value: DataType[K]) => this' is not assignable to type '(key: string, value: AllowedValue) => this'.
      Types of parameters 'key' and 'key' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof DataType'.
export interface TypedMap<DataType extends MapTypeAllowedData<DataType>> 
extends Map<string, AllowedValue> {
                    ~~~~~~~~
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct... Your `TypedMap<DataType>` does not act like a `Map<string, AllowedValue>`.  If I have a `Map<string, AllowedValue>`, I should be able to call `get("randomString")` on it.  But `TypedMap<DataType>` only allows `get()` to be called with a parameter of type `keyof DataType`.  So you get an error.

Perhaps you meant that `TypedMap<DataType>` should act like a `Map<keyof DataType, AllowedValue>` instead?

```
export interface TypedMap<DataType extends MapTypeAllowedData<DataType>>
  extends Map<keyof DataType, AllowedValue> { // changed here

  toJS(): DataType;
  get<K extends keyof DataType>(key: K, notSetValue?: DataType[K]): DataType[K];
  set<K extends keyof DataType>(key: K, value: DataType[K]): this;

}
```

That should hopefully act the way you want.  Good luck!